# Using @ to access some folders in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native, today I found a code that goes like this to access assets folder from `App/Common/Config.js` to `assets/images/category/`. How is that possible? Is this specific to expo react native or is there any namespacing settings that I can use?

```
    imageCategories: {
        foods: require("@images/category/mobile-category-food.jpg"),
        learn: require("@images/category/mobile-category-learn.jpg"),
    }
```

Also for instance:

```
import wp from "@services/WPAPI";
```

That actually imports from `App/Services/WPAPI`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use absolute paths.

For eg: Create a `package.json` inside the `services` folder.

```
{ "name" : '"services"}
```

You can now import stuff like

```
import wp from "@services/WPAPI";
```

Refer for more: [Absolute Imports](https://medium.com/@davidjwoody/how-to-use-absolute-paths-in-react-native-6b06ae3f65d1)

Comment: OMG, that make sense now. Does it work in any folder in my project? This is amazing, just out of curiosity after reading the article. Does this only works on react-native? Or does it work in any npm based projects?